# Singleton typed memory manager

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, pointers

For my resources management, I wanted the objects allocated on the heap to be in a contiguous block of memory. Obviously, each data type then has to have their own chunk of memory. I could have used a vector for this, of course, but the resources need to be aligned properly with a given alignment which a vector can't do (for alignments above 16 bytes). In addition, I wanted the allocation to be faster than standard `new`.

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory>

typedef unsigned __int32 U32;
typedef unsigned __int8  U8;

#define TYPED_ALLOCATION

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifdef TYPED_ALLOCATION
// TODO: the allocation should always return a unique_ptr!
#define MakeUniqueInstance(Type,...) AllocTypedUnique<Type>(__VA_ARGS__)
#define MakeSharedInstance(Type,...) AllocTypedShared<Type>(__VA_ARGS__)

// This defines a deleter functor in a similar way to the default deleter
template<class _Ty>
struct typed_delete
{
    typed_delete() = default;

    template<class _Ty2,
    class = typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Ty2 *, _Ty *>::value,
        void>::type>
        typed_delete( const typed_delete<_Ty2>& ) = default;

    void operator()( _Ty *_Ptr ) const
    {
        FreeTyped( _Ptr );
    }
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
using TypedDeleter = typed_delete < T >;

// Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to make unique pointers of a base type
// while allocating for a derived type (e.g. unique_ptr<Base> pB = TypedAlloc<Derived>(args),
// therefor I had to use shared pointers.
template<class T, class...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T, TypedDeleter<T>> AllocTypedUnique( Args&&... args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, TypedDeleter<T>>( AllocTyped<T>( args... ) );
}

template<class T, class...Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> AllocTypedShared( Args&&... args )
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>( AllocTyped<T>( args... ), TypedDeleter<T>() );
}

template<class T, class...Args>
T* AllocTyped( Args&&... args )
{
    static_assert( sizeof( T ) > 0,
        "Cannot allocate memory for zero-size type" );
    // Allocate a chunk from the typed memory pool
    T* p = TypedAllocator<T>::Get().Allocate();
    // Construct the object in the allocated space
    new ( (void *) p ) T( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    return p;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
void FreeTyped( T* p )
{
    TypedAllocator<T>::Get().Free( p );
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This deleter is used to free the memory allocated by _aligned_alloc function
struct page_delete
{
    page_delete() = default;

    page_delete( const page_delete& ) = default;

    void operator()( char*_Ptr ) const
    {
        _aligned_free( static_cast<void*>( _Ptr ) );
    }
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct Page
{
    std::unique_ptr<char, page_delete> page;
    std::vector<U32> freeChunks;
    U32 end = 0;

    Page() = default;

    Page( Page&& o )
        : page { std::move( o.page ) }
        , freeChunks { std::move( o.freeChunks ) }
        , end { o.end }
    {}

    Page& operator=( Page&& o )
    {
        page = std::move( o.page );
        freeChunks = std::move( o.freeChunks );
        end = o.end;
        return *this;
    }
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// For each type T, there will be one singleton memory manager which will place the instances
// of the object in a contiquous page of memory.
template <class T>
class TypedAllocator
{
public:
    static TypedAllocator<T>& Get()
    {
        static TypedAllocator m_this;

        return m_this;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    T* Allocate()
    {
        const U32 numPages = (U32) pages.size();

        U32 row = 0;
        U32 col = 0;
        // If there are empty slots on the last page, fill it up first
        if ( numPages > 0 && pages.back().end < width )
        {
            row = numPages - 1;
            col = pages.back().end;
            ++pages[row].end;
        }
        else
        {
            // If the last page is full, then go through all pages and see if there's
            // a free chunck to hold the object.
            bool needNewPage = true;
            for ( ; row < numPages; ++row )
            {
                std::vector<U32>& freeChunks = pages[row].freeChunks;
                if ( !freeChunks.empty() )
                {
                    col = freeChunks.back();
                    freeChunks.pop_back();
                    needNewPage = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // All pages are full, so new page is needed.
            if ( needNewPage )
            {
                std::unique_ptr<char, page_delete>
                    uPtr( static_cast<char*>( _aligned_malloc( byteWidth, __alignof( T ) ) ) );

                Page page;
                page.end = 1;
                page.page = std::move( uPtr );
                pages.push_back( std::move( page ) );
            }
        }

        return reinterpret_cast<T*>( pages[row].page.get() + col * stride );
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void Free( T*& ptr )
    {
        const U32 numPages = (U32) pages.size();
        for ( U32 i = 0; i < numPages; ++i )
        {
            const auto tp_begin = pages[i].page.get();
            const auto tp_end = tp_begin + byteWidth;
            const char *const cPtr = reinterpret_cast<const char* const>( ptr );
            if ( cPtr >= tp_begin && cPtr <= tp_end )
            {
                assert( ( cPtr - tp_begin ) % stride == 0 );
                ptr->~T();
                const U32 col = (U32) ( cPtr - tp_begin ) / stride;

                assert( std::find
                    ( pages[i].freeChunks.begin()
                    , pages[i].freeChunks.end()
                    , col ) == pages[i].freeChunks.end() &&
                    "Error: memory at this pointer was already freed!" );

                pages[i].freeChunks.push_back( col );
                // when a page is completely empty, then delete it.
                if ( pages[i].freeChunks.size() == width )
                {
                    pages.erase( pages.begin() + i );
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    TypedAllocator( const TypedAllocator& ) = delete;
    TypedAllocator& operator=( const TypedAllocator& ) = delete;
private:
    TypedAllocator() = default;
    ~TypedAllocator() = default;

    // the aligned size of the object
    const U32 stride{ __alignof(T)* (sizeof(T) / __alignof(T)
        +(U8)((sizeof(T) % __alignof(T)) != 0)) };
    // the width of each page. currently holding just 4 elements for easy debugging.
    const U32 width {4};
    // size of each page in bytes.
    const U32 byteWidth {width * stride};
    std::vector<Page> pages;
};
#else
#define MakeUniqueInstance(Type,...) std::make_unique<Type>(__VA_ARGS__)
#define MakeSharedInstance(Type,...) std::make_shared<Type>(__VA_ARGS__)
template<class T>
using TypedDeleter = std::default_delete < T >;

#endif // TYPED_ALLOCATION
```

First, by all means, use it if you feel it's useful to you. Second, I'd appreciate any suggestion to improve/optimize the design (or why it would ever fail/bugs). I know this implementation is not thread safe, but other than that all suggestions are welcome. The current problem that I have with this is that I cannot use it to write the following:

```
void main()
{
    unique_ptr<Base, TypedDeleter<Base>> pB = MakeUniqueInstance(Derived);
}
```

That's because I can't use `TypedDeleter` the same way `default_delete` is used, so I need help with this.

The most important reason for implementing this allocator is the fact that the allocations for each type are mostly on the same contiguous block. So accessing them repeatedly is more cache friendly. I haven't tested if my allocator is faster than `new`. That'd be nice, but it's not as important as data locality.

Comment: This code is neither complete nor working: where's "..\General\GeneralHeader.h"? Several needed standard library headers aren't shown: `<memory>` (std::unique_ptr, etc.), `<type_traits>` (std::enable_if, etc.), `<vector>`. `using` declarations are not shown: some standard library symbols have `std::`, some don't. Types are out of order (`AllocTypedUnique` depends on and precedes `AllocTyped`, which in turn depends on and precedes `TypedAllocator`). Where is `U32` declared?

Comment: @Niall, I added the necessary headers and typedefs. The types ordering is ok. `AllocTypedUnique` and `AllocTyped` are template functions, not types. I'm using VS C++ and it compiles and runs without errors and warnings. Please note that you should put the code in a header file (.h) and not in a .cpp

Comment: I challenge the assertion **`resources need to be aligned properly with a given alignment which a vector can't do`** Is there something specific to your use case where vectors do not hold?

Comment: Also **`I wanted the allocation to be faster than standard new`**. So technically its possible (allocator pools). But a lot of effort has gone into making new exceedingly fast. I would have to see this as a bottleneck (I never have) before I even tried to optimize it. Because you are trying to implement functionality that already exists and is well debugged (ie known to be correct) there has to be a very good argument for re-implementing it.

Comment: @Loki: last time I checked (VS2010) a vector could not be used to hold data if I'd declared the data with `__declspc(align(64))` for example. Besides, I'd have to manually declare a vector for every data type that I'd like to allocate on the heap. It seemed impractical. Also using `new`, doesn't yield the locality that I'm getting with this. I agree the standard functionality is well tested, but I needed some properties that in my opinion is not offered by other solutions.

Comment: If you have a `vector<X>` the memory allocated for the vector is aligned to `sizeof<X> * vector.size()`.  Anything aligned to for `Y` is also aligned for anything with alignment less than `Y`. Thus as long as you allocate enough space for one `X` then it will be correctly aligned for `X`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8458776/14065

Comment: Locality is best achieved using allocator pools (a well tested technology). Also to be blunt it does not look like your version would be quicker than new (I have not timed it and I could be wrong) but the complexity of the code gives me pause.

Comment: @LokiAstari: It's certainly not alligned to `sizeof(X)*vector.size`, but to `alignof(X)`. Still, you are right with your assertion that one can trivially force a vector to use stronger alignment: Just use a custom allocator.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Anything allocated with new is aligned to at least the size of bytes allocated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8458776/14065

Comment: @LokiAstari You mean it is aligned to at least `gcd(sizeof vector[0]*vector.size, alignof(max_align_t))`. Sure you can get lucky there, but why gamble?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Not quite what I said. But there is no gamble its guaranteed by the standard for all sizes.

Comment: @LokiAstari: What I said is guaranteed by the standard, yes. But the OP wants stronger alignment, which you implied would be there. Thus, a gamble.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What the standard guarantees is: If the block allocated by new is larger than X then it is aligned for any alignment size smaller or equal to X. So an object of size 2 is aligned for 1 and 2. So an object of size 8 is aligned for 8 4 2 1. etc.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I took the wrong operation, but `new` does not guarantee better alignment than `alignof(max_align_t)`, ever. Should have been: min(biggest_power_of_2_not_bigger_than(sizeof vector[0]*vector.size), alignof(max_align_t));

Comment: @Deduplicator: Absolutely true. But no object requires alignment bigger than `alignof(max_align_t)`. Never say never though. So limit it to the context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Starting on page:

```
Page( Page&& o )
    : page { std::move( o.page ) }
    , freeChunks { o.freeChunks }   // You want to copy the free chunks.
                                    // Why not move them?
    , end { o.end }
{}

Page& operator=( Page&& o )
{
    page = std::move( o.page );
    freeChunks.swap( o.freeChunks );  // OK works. fine.
                                      // But it looks more logical if you move it.
    end = o.end;
    return *this;
```

Comment: Good one. I'll edit the main post to apply your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that your code is Visual Studio specific at the moment, so I'll give you a few tips you can use to make it more standard and portable.

1. `#pragma once` is not standard, but it is supported by [several compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability), so this is not an issue. Just for the record, an option to it would be an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).
2. `__int32` and `__int8` are Microsoft specific. C++11 provides the header [`<cstdint>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/), which defines several sized integral types, including `uint32_t` and `uint8_t`. You should use those instead.
3. `__alignof` is a pre-C++11 Visual Studio extension. The new C++ standard now provides the [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) operator, which should be used instead.
4. `_aligned_malloc()` is also a Windows specific function, its Unix equivalent being `memalign()` or `posix_memalign()`. Your best course of action here would be to avoid calling `_aligned_malloc()` directly by creating a thin wrapper function that you can redirect to `memalign`/`_aligned_malloc` easily with some `#ifdefs`, in case you ever decide to port this code. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839922/aligned-malloc-in-gcc) for more.

Comment: Thank you. I'm indeed aware my MS specific usage. However, for most of my projects the target platform is Windows. So, I'm not very concerned with portability. The only downside is that when I'd share my code like this, not every one could readily use it.

Comment: `#pragma once` may not be standard, but it is [widely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability) supported.

Comment: You know what, @tehinternetsismadeofcatz, I think you are right, `#pragma once` is better, and I've based my life on a lie. Heheheh, but seriously, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm not arguing it's better or anything, just pointing out for lazy people like me (whoops) that there's no problem using it! It's something I see quite often judged as "non portable" but it is :p